# GitHub Action Build and Package Python Dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, github, yaml, github-actions

I’m trying to identify what the best practice is when building python dependencies. At the moment the dependencies is grabbing latest version in a range aka nothing less than 3.0 and nothing greater than 4.0.

We would like the dependencies to be immutable where packages are zipped up and stored in the repository when running a pipeline.

We are using Git Hub Actions and would like to introduce Release Tags so we can fall back in case dependency issue and we can revert to the previous working dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used GitHub Actions personally but I gather the principle is the same as running a virtual environment. I would always generate a fixed 'requirements.txt' using:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

on a working tested version of the code. Then loosen package version numbers / conditions when trying to upgrade dependencies, before relocking the requirements.txt once tested environmentally (package conflicts) and functionally.

Leaving pip installer to decide which package to use is not recommended if running a process of importance, due to the potential for functionality changes that could create errors in execution.